# Bootstrap video modal not displaying once exited and re-opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal that plays a YouTube video once the play button is clicked. Then when someone exits the modal, and re-opens it, the modal is empty with no YouTube embedded:

[image]

Here is the JS code that opens and closes the modal:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = $("BetterConnect").attr("src");
    $("#BetterConnectModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
      $("#BetterConnect").attr("src", "");
    });
    $("#BetterConnectModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
      $("#BetterConnect").attr("src", url);
    });
  });
```

**Here is my HTML for the actual modal and play button:**

```
          <div class="play-icon">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#BetterConnectModal" class="play-button" >
              <img src="https://images.play-button.svg" class="play-icon-1" />
            </a>
          </div>

          <img
            src="https://images.background-img.jpg"/>
          <div id="BetterConnectModal" class="modal fade" style="display: none">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <iframe id="BetterConnect" width="450" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/skFzBaX41NM?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
                  </iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Any ideas why it's not playing back?

Comment: Can you confirm for the 2nd line of JS you actually are using `var url = $("#BetterConnect").attr("src");` (sample is missing the `#`)

Comment: @SteveHynding you are right. It's missing the #. Thank you for the catch.